# Is there a way to stop implicit pointer conversions to void *

Tags: c++, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, void-pointers

I need to find all such places in my source code where a pointer of any type is implicitly converted to `void *` or a way to stop these implicit conversions.

For example:

1. `int *` to `void *`
2. `char *` to `void *`
3. `Base *` to  `void *`

Is there any **gcc** warning or error flag which detects all such lines where a pointer is implicitly converted to `void *`?

Comment: I'm not aware of one, but it's a good idea.  There really should be _no_ implicit conversion to `void*`, given how dangerous it is, but history...

Comment: `grep "(void*)" * -R` ?

Comment: @JamesKanze : the danger doesn't really lie with the conversion to `void*`, but rather with a subsequent conversion from `void*` back to the wrong type. The latter already generates an error with g++, and the [`-Wc++-compat`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) flag can be used to also generate a warning with gcc. Afaik, the former can't be made to generate a warning or error for either gcc or g++.

Comment: @Dabo That's not very implicit.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The problem lies in the round trip.  If you have to explicitly convert to `void*`, you're more likely to be aware of what's going on.  (But maybe not really.  How many times have I seen people pass a `new Derived(...)` as last argument to `pthread_create`, and convert the `void*` to `Base*` at the top of the new thread's function.  Sometimes even with explicit conversions at both ends.  I suspect that this sort of problem is more frequent in C++ than in C, because of derivation.)

Comment: @dyp just the implicit conversion to void*

Comment: Seems to me like a perfectly valid upcast: `myVoidPtr = myIntPtr;`. Type `void *` just means 'I don't care what type of data is referenced'; any type will do. If you feel that is a bad thing, then don't use variables and parameters of type `void *` in your program. I am really curious about your use case.

Comment: -1 for asking about implicit pointer conversions and tagging the question both C and C++ without clarifying in the body of the question what you mean by that.

Comment: @JamesKanze : makes sense - adding warnings on both ends makes it more visible. There's a risk it creates a false sense of security (à la "I fixed the warning by adding an explicit cast, so now things are ok"), but then you can't help people that insist on shooting themselves in the foot.

Answer (score 4):

Say you have a simple program like

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char* apples = "apples and pears";
   char fruit[1024];
   void* avoid;
   int aint;
   float afloat;

   avoid = &aint;
   avoid = &afloat;
   memcpy(fruit, apples, strlen(apples) + 1);
}
```

Here is a trick that will tell you where some of the implicit conversions are happening.  Add this at the start of the program

```
#define void double
```

You will get a lot of compile errors: including where the implicit conversions are happening.  It won't spot void* = double* so you'll need to try again with

```
#define void int
```

to spot the rest.

Comment: It won't spot the implicit conversion from `char[1024]` to `void*` for passing `fruit` to `memcpy` unless you define it before including `string.h`. And if you do that, you might get linker errors (for more complex functions) or other problems with intrinsics.

Comment: Didn't know that memcpy was intrinsic on some compilers.  You learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
gcc -Dvoid="struct doesnotexistanywhere" myfile.c
```

This will complain about all implicit conversions from and to `void*`. There will be false positives for at least these cases:

```
void function( ...
int function(void) { 
(void)statement;
```

Corresponding messages can be just filtered out with `grep`, or you can refactor the code to exclude these cases.

Needless to say, even if the compilation somehow succeeds, you should not use the resulting objects. In my experiment, a program that `#include`d stdio.h, memory.h and string.h compiled cleanly, so this is indeed possible, but the standard explicitly disallows this and who knows what kind of code the compiler can generate.